# How can I type the Mathematica symbols “Distributed” and “Conditioned”

Tags: symbols

How can I type the Mathematica symbols “Distributed” and “Conditioned”?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I cant find these symbols. Could you name any other reference or some paper where you have seen them. They don't seem to be in unicode for now.

Comment: the "Conditioned" symbol resembles unicode 27ED. although that is intended as a right delimiter; that would be in the stix or xits fonts.  the other is not in unicode.  if, as requested by @LaRiFaRi, another published reference can be found using these symbols, i will be happy to submit them for unicode consideration.

Comment: There's a [posting about another way to add symbols](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185595/) that may help.

Answer (score 5):

I've got the feeling that these two symbols do not exist in the unicode standard. So I would recommend to draw them by yourself in TikZ or to copy the images and include them using the package `graphicx`.

If you can find any other references for these symbols, you can submit them to unicode or to the font developer of your choice.

Barbara Beeton surmises that the "Conditioned" symbol could be the unicode `U+27ED`. I am not sure, if this is the correct sign, but I have searched similar closing (right) delimiters for you. Maybe, one of them is fine for you.

The normal sign for distributed is a standard tilde. So maybe you do not even need the exotic symbol of Mathematica. Search this homepage for normal, wide, and bold tildes in all forms and colors...

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\row}[2]{\texttt{U+#2} & {\setmathfont{xits-math} $#1$} & {\setmathfont{asana-math} $#1$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
unicode & XITS version & Asana version\\
\midrule
\row{\Rbrbrak}{27ED}\\
\row{\rBrack}{27E7}\\
\row{\rBrace}{2984}\\
\row{\rParen}{2986}\\
\row{\rrparenthesis}{2988}\\
\row{\rrangle}{298A}\\
\row{\rblkbrbrak}{2998}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I thought it would be prudent to ask Mathematica first. The function `TexForm` was quite helpful:

```
TeXForm[x \[Distributed] y]
```

returned

```
x\unicode{f3d2}y
```

I checked [this Unicode lookup site](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+F3D2) and it said that code `F3D2` is a "private use area" which I don't quite understand. And, sadly, LaTeXiT, my preferred program for quickly generating formulae, doesn't seem to understand `\unicode{f3d2}` even though I had `package[utf8]{inputenc}` in the preamble; it says "Undefined control sequence".

With Python, `print("\uf3d2")` returned


which I have difficulty reproducing here. In my terminal window it actually showed up as a question mark in a box...

I realise this is not an answer but it would have been difficult to put all this in a comment, especially the Python part.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/246053)

Comment: The "Private Use Area" is an area of codepoints that are reserved for private use (hence the name). This means that these codepoints are not standardised. It rather depends on the font how to render a certain codepoint. Therefore, the information that the character U+F3D2 should be chosen does not help at all, since this is not a "meaningful" codepoint.

Comment: The conclusion should probably not be that `U+F3D2` is the correct codepoint, but that Wolfram do not consider this symbol to exist in Unicode, while surmised in the [existing answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184567) it isn't demonstrated there. The documentation also places the [Distributed](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Distributed.html) and [Conditioned](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Conditioned.html) characters in the Private Use Area.

Comment: @Miyase Please note that I _did_ write "I realise this is not an answer..." but the details would have been difficult to add as a comment. At least this modest contribution prompted valuable comments from Jasper Habicht and Dai Bowen, in this respect it was not entirely useless... :-)

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yes, I was suspecting this. The consensus that seems to emerge that there's no standardised and _reproducible_ way of writing the '\\[Distributed]` symbol outside Mathematica.