# Problems with custom symbols

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to include some custom symbols in LaTeX. So I have some vector graphic images that I export to PDF, such as:

[image: My Symbol]

and I include them in LaTeX using
`\newcommand*\mysymbol{\includegraphics{mysymbol.pdf}}`.

I have two problems:

1. The positioning in equations is off (it's above the line even though the image itself has no borders):

   [image]
2. I cannot use it as a subscript (which I would like). For example, `$H_\mysymbol$` throws the following error:

   ```
   ./mytex.tex:1000: Missing { inserted. 
   <to be read again> 
                       \let  
   l.1000 $H_\mysymbol
                      $
   ?
   ```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\xmysymbol{\raisebox{-.7ex}{\includegraphics[height=2.2ex]{mysymbol}}}
\newcommand\mysymbol{{\mathchoice{\xmysymbol}{\xmysymbol}{\hbox{\scriptsize\xmysymbol}}{\hbox{\tiny\xmysymbol}}}}

\begin{document}

\[\chi(x \in \mysymbol)\]

$\chi(x \in \mysymbol)$

$X_\mysymbol  + X_{x_\mysymbol}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17):

Just one trick instead of several. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newcommand*{\mysymbol}{%
  \text{% change size in subscripts or superscripts
    \includegraphics[
      height=1.5ex,% adjust to suit
      valign=M,% center vertically
      raise=\fontdimen22\textfont2,% but raise it to the formula axis
    ]{YWWMA}}
}

\begin{document}
\[
\frac{1}{2}+\mysymbol-
H_\mysymbol \in \mysymbol^{\mysymbol^\mysymbol}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**Remarks:**

- The symbol is located at the base line. Probably you want to center it around the math axis (like `+`, `×`, ...).
- The height of the symbol is not defined. The example uses the height of `H`.
- Subscripts and superscripts are *not* arguments, thus the rule that curly braces can be omitted, if there is only one token does not apply. It only works, if the token expands to a math symbol or subformula. The curly braces work, because they form a subformula.
- The example uses `\resizebox`, because it is more flexible than options to `\includegraphics`. Then other stuff (`tikzpicture`, ...) can be used instead of `\includegraphics`.
- The repeated use of `\includegraphics` can be avoided by using a box register. The image is stored in box register `\mysymbolbox` and reused in macro `\mysymbol`. This also avoids that the `.log` file is flooded with information data about the image `mysymbol`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\mysymbolbox}
\sbox{\mysymbolbox}{\includegraphics{myimage}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mysymbol}{%
  {% subformula in math that allows: H_\mysymbol
    \mathpalette{\@mysymbol}{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@mysymbol}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \settoheight{\dimen@}{$#1H$}% \dimen@ is a local scratch dimen register
  \vcenter{\hbox{% vertical centering around math axis
    \resizebox*{!}{\dimen@}{% total height = \dimen@
      \usebox{\mysymbolbox}%
    }%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  H_\mysymbol \in \mysymbol^{\mysymbol^\mysymbol}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### TikZ

Answers in the [symbols](/questions/tagged/symbols) tag are not complete without TikZ (at least quite often):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox\myimagebox
\sbox\myimagebox{% avoid space by line end
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    x=1ex,
    y=1ex,
    line width=.7pt,% between semithick and thick
    line join=round,
  ]
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,-1) -- (3,1) -- (4,0) -- (3,-1) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
    \fill (0,0) -- (.5,-.5) -- (1.5,.5) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}% avoid space by line end
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mysymbol}{%
  {% subformula in math that allows: H_\mysymbol
    \mathpalette{\@mysymbol}{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@mysymbol}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \settoheight{\dimen@}{$#1H$}% \dimen@ is a local scratch dimen register
  \vcenter{\hbox{% vertical centering around math axis
    \resizebox*{!}{\dimen@}{% total height = \dimen@
      \usebox\myimagebox
      % \includegraphics{mysymbol}%
    }%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  H_\mysymbol \in \mysymbol^{\mysymbol^\mysymbol}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result TikZ]

### Variant

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\mysymbol}{%
  \text{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\mysymbolHeight{height("$H$")}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\mysymbolLineWidth{\mysymbolHeight*.07}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\MathAxis{height("$\vcenter{}$")}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      x=\mysymbolHeight,
      y=\mysymbolHeight,
      line width=\mysymbolLineWidth,
      line join=round,
      baseline=-\MathAxis,
    ]
      \draw (0,0)--(.5,-.5)--(1.5,.5)--(2,0)--(1.5,-.5)--(.5,.5)--cycle;
      \fill (0,0)--(.25,-.25)--(.75,.25)--(.5,.5)--cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\[
  H_\mysymbol \in \mysymbol^{\mysymbol^\mysymbol}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\newcommand*\mysymbol{\raisebox{-1ex}{\includegraphics{mysymbol}}}
```

and

```
$H_{\mysymbol}$
```